# XML schema validation results "Attribute not declared"

Tags: c#, xsd

I validate an XML document against my XML schema. I recently added a new attribute in the XML files and the XSD schema. But when doing the validation I always get an exception

> *base{System.EventArgs}: {System.XML.Shema.ValidationEventArgs}
>
>   Exception: "The Anhaenger-Attribute is not declared.
>
>   Message: "The Anhaenger-Attribute is not declared.*

Here the declaration in my XSD schema:

```
<xs:attribute id="Anhaenger" name="Anhaenger" use="optional">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="D2TAnhaenger_Type" />
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:simpleType id="D2TAnhaenger_Type" name="D2TAnhaenger_Type">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="70" />
      <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

and this is the attribute in the XML file:

```
 Anhaenger="ANH - 0815"
```

Here the code I use for doing the correction in my application:

```
protected XmlDocument ValidateAndCorrect(Stream XMLStream)
{
    // Verwenden von XMLReader, damit die Schemainformationen an den Knoten angefügt werden.
    // Dann können wir später korrigieren.
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.Schemas.Add("", m_SchemaFile);
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

    // Dokument aus dem Stream holen.
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    XMLStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(XMLStream, settings);
    document.Load(reader);

    int i = 0;

    bool validate = true;
    while (validate)
    {
        i++;
        Debug.WriteLine("--- Validierung und Korrektur beginnt ---");
        Debug.WriteLine("Durchlauf Nummer: " + i.ToString());

        m_errors = new List<ValidationEventArgs>();
        document.Validate(this.ValidationEventHandler);
        validate = CorrectValidationResult(document.ChildNodes);
    }

    return document;
}
```

So, does anyone have an idea what I do wrong? Many thanks for any help

Best regards
Adleano

Answer (score 0):

The catch is in the target namespace of your XSD; I guess (you're not showing the xs:schema attribute set) that since your XML attribute is declared global, it must be prefixed with an alias which matches your schema's targetNamespace.